# Trouble communicating with a ledger via APDU command trying to get SECP256K1 key

Tags: cryptocurrency, libusb, apdu, ledger-nano-s

I've been following the spec written [here](https://github.com/cosmos/ledger-cosmos/blob/main/docs/APDUSPEC.md) using the cosmos app on my ledger, but I am getting rather unhelpful errors. The exact information that I am sending to my ledger looks like this

```
running 1 test
command: ApduCommand {
    cla: 85,
    ins: 4,
    p1: 1,
    p2: 0,
    length: 27,
    data: [],
}
data: [6, 99, 111, 115, 109, 111, 115, 44, 0, 0, 0, 118, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[ 64] << 01010500000005550401001b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[  2] << 6984
Error: Ledger(Apdu("[APDU_CODE_DATA_INVALID] data reversibly blocked (invalidated)"))
```

If anyone has any info on what's going on here it would be greatly appreciated. This is specifically trying to return the SECP256K1 public key, and you can see above for the derivation path I am using [44, 118, 0, 0, 0] in 32bit little endian.
The HRP is "cosmos" and HRP_LENGTH is set to 6.